# mongoose populate makes the field empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas:

```
const categorySchema = Schema({
slug: {
    type: String,
    index: true
},
tags: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'Tag'
    }
});
```

and:

```
const tagSchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['bool', 'selectable', 'int']
    },
    categories: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }],
    possibleValues: [String]
});
```

Now here is the problem. When I try to populate my category instance with tags, the whole field, becomes an empty array, while when there are no `.populate()` statements, there are some `ObjectId`s there. What is the problem?

**Update:** here is my query:

```
models.Category
            .findOne({_id: req.params.categoryId})
            .populate('tags')
            .then(category => {
                console.log(category);
                res.send(category.tags);
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Category Schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var categorySchema = Schema({
slug: {type: String,index: true},
tags: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],ref: 'Tag'}
},{
    collection:'categories'
 });

var Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

Tag Schema :

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


    var tagSchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['bool', 'selectable', 'int']
    },
    categories: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }],
    possibleValues: [String]
},{
    collection:'tags'
 });


var Tag = mongoose.model('Tag', tagSchema);
```

Find Query :

```
Category.
  findOne({_id: req.params.categoryId}).
  populate('tags').
  exec(function (err, categories) {
    return res.json(categories);
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain why did I had to do this? @Dhruvin

Comment: @Masious , you need to use exec() function after populate

Comment: Not true. You can use the Promise approach just as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the schema definition of `category.tags` to this:

```
tags: [{ 
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tag'
}]
```